# JavaFX TableView: Cell padding / border makes sort indicator shift

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I experienced a strange problem with TableView styling in JavaFX (*caspian.css*): I want my cells to have a 1px padding or 1px transparent border. However, if I apply either of them, the column sort indicator shifts to the right.

**How can I visually separate the table cells while keeping the sort arrow in place?**

**Case 1:** Arrow is in place, cells are not separated.

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-background-color: #FBFBFB;
  -fx-cell-size: 58px;
}
```

[image: Case 1]

**Case 2:** Arrow shifts, cells are separated

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-background-color: #FBFBFB;
  -fx-cell-size: 58px;

  -fx-border-style: solid;
  -fx-border-color: transparent; /** This causes trouble */
  -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
```

[image: Case 2]

**Case 3:** Arrow shifts, cells are separated

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-background-color: #FBFBFB;
  -fx-cell-size: 58px;

  -fx-padding: 1 1 1 1; /** This causes trouble, too */
}
```

[image: Case 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the following style sheet

```
.table-row-cell {
  -fx-background-color: #FBFBFB;
  -fx-cell-size: 58px;

  /** Nothing else done here */
}
```

and removing the padding of the *Delivery date* cell in my Java code

```
this.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;");
```

solved the problem for me.